# Writing DataFrame to class '_io.BufferedWriter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, argparse

I use a parser.argparser class to parse the command line arguments in my script. It's handy, as it automatically checks for the file existence, permissions, etc. of the file names passed as command arguments and immediately throws exceptions if something is wrong. It can also handle '-' convention to open stdin/stdout streams. Ultimately it returns a ready-to-use file object:

```
CommonArguments.add_argument('-o',  '--output',         type=argparse.FileType('wb'),   required=True,  help='Output file name')
print("Object type:", type(parser.parse_args().output))
-------
Object type: <class '_io.BufferedWriter'>
```

It works well if I want to use built-in functions to read and write from the file. However, since I process the data in DataFrames, it would be handy to pass the object to a DataFrame method to save the file or to  read from it. Unfortunately, the df.to_excel() method requires a filename and handles all the file IO by itself, so I end up using:

```
df.to_excel(parser.parse_args().output.name, index=False)
```

Is it at all possible to make the two libraries work together in a more streamlined fashion? What I would actually need to do is to collect the data in an excel format from the DataFrame and dump it to the BufferedWriter object for writing. I'm somewhat concerned using two distinct objects accessing the same file.

The same goes for the input: I'd like to collect the data from the BufferedReader (which could be STDIN if I pass '-' as a file name), and create a dataframe from it, similarly to:

```
df = pd.read_html(source_object)
```

Unfortunately, I can't make pd.read_html read from stdin.

Is it at all possible?

Or am I missing something and there is a better solution?

Comment: Have you looked at passing an excelwriter to `to_excel` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html ?

Comment: `FileType is a simple class in the argparse.py source.  You could write your own type function to open the file as you want.

Answer (score 0):

`FileType` was written as a convenience tool for scripts that take input/output files. It has not aged well with the transition to Py3.

Years ago I wrote a patch for a bug/issue that wanted the equivalent of a `with context`, a file object that would automatically close itself. It was too much work to put into production.

I think accepting just a filename, and doing your own with `open`, or `pandas open` is better.

But if you still want the benefits of error checking, a custom `type` function is probably the way to go. It shouldn't be hard to write. –